# Permission is ALLOWED but not WRITE Android AngularJS with Ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

Hello everybody I have a problem a long time and decided to post , on some devices I can not write anything , this happens especially in mobile phone android(4.1-4.4) that does not have sdcard.
Some phones usually work ( especially with android 5.0 ) with or without SDCARD .

My routine is: 
CHECKS(READ) **localStorage** ->

**IF OK** : AUTH AUTOMATIC -> UPDATE LOCALSTORAGE -> GO HOME PAGE.

**ELSE** : USERS INFORMATION LOGIN AND PASSWORD -> AUTH -> SAVE LOCALSTORAGE -> GO HOME PAGE.

ALREADY TRIED USE : SQLITE AND FILE.

but in some phones especially with android ( 4.1 - 4.4 and without SDCARD ) he finds no content in LocalStorage , so every time the User open the app it needs to inform login and password.

OBS:
1. I checked the AndroidManifest and i HAVE WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ.

2. when installed on an emulator android 4.1 without SDCARD , I encounter the following error in CMD " rm failed for -f , Read only file system"

My permissions

- whitelist
- camera
- media-capture
- device
- statusbar
- file
- file-transfer
- imagepicker
- media
- network-information
- file-opener2
- sqlite-storage
- ms-adal
- x-toast
- socialsharing

Thank you in advance